# JS - Onload event not firing

Tags: javascript, html, onload

This fires the onload event:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body onload="alert('Hello')">
<p> Demo </p>
</body>
</html>
```

This does not fire the onload event:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<p id="demo" onload="alert('Hello')"> Demo </p>
</body>
</html>
```

In the second example, why is the event not firing?

Comment: Because your `p` never gets _loaded_ it just gets read, parsed etc... Then when the `body` is loaded (parsing has finished etc...), the event gets fired. In short, only the `body` and its parents receive that event.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The elements that support `onload` are

```
<body>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>, <input type="image">, <link>, <script>, <style>
```

A way to access any other element on load could be by adding a script tag, like below, though it depends very much on what you want to achieve

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
      <p id="demo"> Demo </p>
      <script>console.log( document.getElementById('demo').textContent );</script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

the `onload` **property/event** is only for the body, if you want to make some modifications to the `<p>` you should do it in a function defined in the **body** `onload` property