# How can I draw Canvas conditional onload with v-if?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, html5-canvas

I'm new to Vue and JavaScript, so please help me understand this problem:

I want to dynamically showload different canvas elements on a page.
The drawing of the canvas is defined in a seperate script.js file.

Here's a section of my code:

```
<canvas v-if="checkedBoxes.includes('Heart')" onload="drawHeart();" id="heartCanvas" width="300" height="240"></canvas>
<canvas v-if="checkedBoxes.includes('Star')" onload="drawStar();" id="starCanvas" width="240" height="240"></canvas>
```

script.js:

```
function drawHeart() {
let heartCanvas = document.getElementById("heartCanvas");
let c = heartCanvas.getContext('2d');
c.beginPath();
... }
```

However, when a canvas element appears, it is not drawn by the Javascript function drawXY(). It seems to me that the onload event is not triggered when the element appears on the page. I also tried it with the Vue expression `v-on:load="drawXY"` without success. When i change the event trigger to `onclick`, it works, but that's not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally found a solution for my problem!

As I learned, onload events are not supported on every HTML element, only a few such as `<body>, <frame>, <iframe>, <img>` , ...
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42004669

So I added an empty image after the canvas element, which executes the drawXY() function on load of the image.

Here's the updated code:

```
<template v-if="checkedBoxes.includes('Heart')">
    <canvas id="heartCanvas" width="300" height="240"></canvas>
    <!-- empty image for onload event -->
    <img onload="drawHeart();" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" width="0" height="0" alt="" />
</template>

<template v-if="checkedBoxes.includes('Star')">
    <canvas id="starCanvas" width="240" height="240"></canvas>
    <!-- empty image for onload event -->
    <img onload="drawStar();" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAD/ACwAAAAAAQABAAACADs=" width="0" height="0" alt="" />
</template>
```

It's the best workarround I've found, as other variants such as executing the function right after a checkbox is selected usually end up not working because the `<canvas>` element is not yet rendered and as a consequence, `document.getElementById` returns null. `<script>` tags are not allowed within v-if templates as they could have nasty side-effects.

But if you have a better solution, please feel free to share it!

Comment: Also a similar problem is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670482/canvas-onload-event-isnt-firing#comment34534892_22670643